# video object classification suggestion

Tags: tensorflow, classification

I am trying to build an outdoor smoke detection from the neighbor chimneys. 
I live in a neighborhood where a couple of houses are still using wood-burning fireplaces and cause lots of smoke and they do during the day time. when it is smoky outside, the kid's room sometime has windows open and smoke get in and very hard to get smoke out. The worst part is it is not illegal (yet) so I found little help apart from talking to them and react to it quickly, in vain.

I am thinking to have an outdoor camera looking at chimneys and detect smoke. Then a program sends a text message for alerting. Most time, the image is pretty still and not a lot of variations. It shouldn't be a too hard problem for classification I imagine? I have little experience with Tensorflow or machine learning but I am a good programmer. So given some direction and some existing model, I hope I can get this working...

I know this sounds desperate, nevertheless, for a good deed. Please help.

Comment: Your motivation is very noble, but you might want to make you question a bit more specific (StackOverflow is more for specific questions than for general suggestions). Anyway TensorFlow might indeed be a good idea, and you could start from a tutorial like this one: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification

Answer (score 0):

For fire and smoke classification, you can check the following tutorial: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/11/18/fire-and-smoke-detection-with-keras-and-deep-learning/.

PyImageSearch is a very good website for image processing, you can find there many articles which can help you (even deployment of neural networks on RaspberryPi and so on).